# Unity Changing cubemap slot in materials

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

I have a material with its shader set to Skybox/Cubemap and I have cubemap1 assigned to the slot. Now I want to replace cubemap1 with cubemap2 and I found a script for this, but i can't seem to get it working.

any thoughts?

```
#pragma strict
var cubemap2 : Cubemap; //Change texture for cubemap
var shaderCubemap : Material; //Shader with cubemapslot

function Start () {
        shaderCubemap.SetTexture("_Cube",cubemap2);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
shaderCubemap.SetTexture("_Tex",cubemap2);
```

When you are not sure about a texture name in a shader, set it to debug in the top right corner of the inspector. It will display the shader and all its parameters with the naming actually used in it.

Comment: It works! Also great tip, I didn't know about the debug function in the inspector.  thank you!